# react-native link giving error no such file or directory info.plist

Tags: javascript, react-native, fonts, info.plist

I am trying to add new font to my react-native project.

I have added this in package.json

```
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

And added corresponding font file in **assets** folder as well in project.

In the process to link the font I need to run -

```
react-native link
```

But while running the above command I am getting this error -

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/private/var/native-testProject/ios/"tests_tvOSTests/Info.plist"'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:667:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:572:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/www/native-testProject/node_modules/react-native-code-push/scripts/postlink/ios/postlink.js:63:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

While looking into the project structure I was able to locate the `info.plist` file as well.

I am quite new to react-native and I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: This error basically arrived when there are wrong path, invalid file name and missing file in projects. Please see there again this Info.plist file stands for tvOS, Make sure file available at "/private/var/native-testProject/ios/"tests_tvOSTests/Info.plist".

Comment: @PaulMarshal I don't know how that folder got created and what is the actual purpose of that folder.

Comment: This folder automatically created when you create new project in react native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looking at the documentation I found that I need to run

```
react-native upgrade
```

My issue was then that some how `tests_tvOSTests` was not getting referenced in the project structure, when I ran upgrade every thing was in place.